# Is there a way to sort an unsorted list with some repeated elements?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I am trying to sort an unsorted list [4, 5, 9, 9, 0, 1, 8]

The list has two repeated elements. I have tried to approach the question by having a loop that goes through each element comparing each element with the next in the list and then placing the smaller element at the start of the list.

```
    def sort(ls:
         ls[x]
         x = [4, 5, 9, 9, 0, 1, 8]
          while len(x) > 0:
             for i in the range(0, len(x)):
               lowest = x[i]
               ls.append(lowest)
```

Please, could someone explain where I am going wrong and how the code should work?

It may be that I have incorrectly thought about the problem and my reasoning for how the code should work is not right

Comment: Code lines within for loop is missing in your question. Can you please share the entire code block? Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I had listed all of the code I had written...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try x.sort() or sorted(x). Check this out https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted. Also, in your program I don't see you making any comparisons, for example, if x[i] <= x[i+1] then ... 
This block of code is just gonna append all the elements in the same order, till n*n times. 
Also check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: I know that there is a sort function but I wanted to write a piece of code that would sort the list in ascending order without using a sort function explicitly. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here check this out https://medium.com/@george.seif94/a-tour-of-the-top-5-sorting-algorithms-with-python-code-43ea9aa02889 . This has 5 different way to sort.

Comment: @NameetNameet better to add the links from SO itself

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if this is exactly what you are looking for but try: `sorted(ListObject)`.
`sorted()` returns the elements of the list from the smallest to the biggest. If one element is repeated, the repeated element is right after the original element. Hope that helped.

Comment: I wanted to write a piece of code without used the sort function to sort the unordered list so the code would re-arrange the list from  [4, 5, 9, 9, 0, 1, 8] --> [0,1,4,5,8,9,9] is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is what `sorted()` does.

Answer (score 0):

For a built-in Python function to sort, let y be your original list, you can use either sorted(y) or y.sort().Keep in mind that sorted(y) will return a new list so you would need to assign it to a variable such as x=sorted(y); whereas if you use x.sort() it will mutate the original list in-place, so you would just call it as is.

If you're looking to actually implement a sorting function, you can try Merge Sort or Quick Sort which run in O (n log n) in which will handle elements with the same value. You can check this out if you want -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-merge-sort/   . For an easier to understand sorting algorithm, Insertion or Bubble sort also handle duplicate as well but have a longer runtime O (n^2) -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/ .

But yea, I agree with Nameet, what you've currently posted looks like it would just append in the same order.

Try one of the above suggestions and hopefully this helps point you in the right direction to if you're looking for a built-in function or to implement a sort, which can be done in multiple ways with different adv and disadv to each one. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the links however I am trying to write the code without using a built-in search function. Do you have any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Yup, in addition to what everyone else has provided, this is a good link to check out which also addresses what you're looking for:   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sorting_algorithms.htm

Comment: As just reading the code examples might be difficult, I also have found looking up visuals such as these helpful (0:21) -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGzPmgsI-pQ

Comment: @AndyPandy better to add the links from SO itself

Answer (score 0):

There are several popular ways for sorting. take bubble sort as an example,

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    x = len(array)
    while(x > 1): # the code below make sense only there are at least 2 elements in the list
        for i in range(x-1): # maximum of i is x-2, the last element in arr is arr[x-1]

            if array[i] > array[i+1]:
                array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
        x -= 1
    return array

x = [4, 5, 9, 9, 0, 1, 8]
bubbleSort(x)
```

---

your code has the same logic as below

```
def sorts(x):
    ls = []
    while len(x) > 0:
        lowest = min(x)
        ls.append(lowest)
        x.remove(lowest)
    return ls 
x = [4, 5, 9, 9, 0, 1, 8]
sorts(x)
#output is [0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9]
```